# nginx: try_files doesn't work, error_page does

Tags: nginx

In my root dir I have:

```
index.html
page-not-found/index.html
```

My config looks like:

```
server {
  ...
  root /var/www/www.example.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /page-not-found/index.html =404;
  }
}
```

But when I'm trying to open non existing file I see default 404 page, not "/page-not-found/index.html". Why?

I also tested

```
error_page 404 = /page-not-found/index.html;
```

instead of try_files directive and it's working fine. So what is wrong with my try_files? I'm using nginx 1.6.2.

Edit: debug doesn't show anything related to try_files

```
2015/02/03 22:27:02 [debug] 10908#0: *1197 http filename: "/var/www/www.example.com/adsds"
2015/02/03 22:27:02 [debug] 10908#0: *1197 add cleanup: 0000000002197148
2015/02/03 22:27:02 [error] 10908#0: *1197 open() "/var/www/www.example.com/adsds" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /adsds HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
2015/02/03 22:27:02 [debug] 10908#0: *1197 http finalize request: 404, "/adsds?" a:1, c:1
2015/02/03 22:27:02 [debug] 10908#0: *1197 http special response: 404, "/adsds?"
```

Comment: try removing the `=404` it's not needed in your condition, and see if it works

Comment: I tried that too, no difference. I updated my question with debug logs.

Comment: Could you post your complete configuration? There is obviously something fishy here but it is not related to the configuration part you posted.

Comment: I had some "if" statements responsible for checking $http_accept_language in my "/" location. I just moved them to the server level and now try_files is working fine. It's strange because all I do in "if" is

                if ($http_accept_language ~* '^([a-z][a-z])') {
                        set $first_language $1;
                }

to get first two chars. No rewrites etc.

Comment: Thanks @PiotrPankowski. I too had same issue. I removed unnecessary if statements from location block and it worked.